# How to conditionally display an input textbox or a list box for a singe- or multiple- row result set?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Paper count if unique paper show inputbox value set value but count multiple paper (if count same 2 paper) create a listbox set option paper.

Notice that Paper1 - Paper3 each have just one Title value. Notice that Paper4 - Paper5 have three distinct Title values.  I want to display just a text box for Paper1 - Paper3 and a list box for Paper4 and Paper5.

```
     mysql fetch record 
      **id       groupoptional        title**
      1           Paper1              Title1
      2           Paper2              Title2
      3           Paper3              Title3
      4           Paper4              Title4
      5           Paper4              Title5
      6           Paper4              Title6
      7           Paper5              Title7
      8           Paper5              Title8
      9           Paper5              Title9
```

Some examples:

```
   create html input 1 <input name="Paper1" type="text" value='1'> Title1
   create html input 2 <input name="Paper2" type="text" value='2'> Title2
   create html input 3 <input name="Paper3" type="text" value='3'> Title3

    create html listbox Paper4 -> <select name='paper4'>
                                  <option value="4">Title 4</option>
                                  <option value="5">Title 5</option>
                                  <option value="6">Title 6</option>
                                  </select>

     create html listbox Paper5 -> <select name='paper5'>
                                   <option value="7">Title 7</option>
                                   <option value="8">Title 8</option>
                                   <option value="9">Title 9</option>
                                   </select>
```

Comment: What's youre problem??? Can you be more clear?

Comment: php mysql fatch record add single value in input box but multiple value add listbox create

Comment: Mr. Maurya, with all respect, your original question title is a candidate for first prize in tangled English syntax. Respectfully, please enlist the help of a colleague when asking questions.

Comment: Use an `if` statement and decide whether to display a textbox or a select? Quite hard to understand the question. Sorry..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is somewhat hard to figure out exactly what you're asking, I think you want something like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, groupoptional, title FROM tableName";
$results = $db->query($sql);

$newArray = array();

foreach($results as $row)
{
    if(isset($newArray[$row["groupoptional"]]))
    {
        $newArray[$row["groupoptional"]][] = array("id" => $row["id"], "title" => $row["title"]);
    }
    else
    {
        $newArray[$row["groupoptional"]] = array(array("id" => $row["id"], "title" => $row["title"]));
    }
}

foreach($newArray as $key => $value)
{
    if(count($value) > 1)
    {
        echo "<select name='".$key."'>";
        foreach($value as $group)
        {
            echo "<option value='".$group["id"]."'>".$group["title"]."</option>";
        }
        echo "</select>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<input type='text' name='".$key."' value='".$value[0]["id"]."'> ".$value[0]["title"];
    }
}
```

Comment: $results = $db->query($sql); show error : Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object

Comment: @d-sonu In this example, $db is an instance of a PDO object.  You could use a different mysql interface if you wanted though.  To learn more about PDO, see http://au.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php